# Как можно организовать Maven-монорепозиторий, включающий клиентский и серверный проекты?

Tags: java, maven

На момент написания этого вопроса, я уже мыслил категориями "Архитектура проекта", "Сильная связанность" и т. д., однако опыта написания реальных проектов конкретно на Java у меня пока было, поэтому если я буду говорить абсурдные вещи с точки зрения Java или Maven - пожалуйста, разъясните их.

Итак, помещать клиентскую часть и серверную часть в один проект удобно прежде всего потому, что можно использовать единую бизнес-логику (если и клиент, и сервер написаны на одном языке, что в случае с Java возможно). Не вдаваясь в то, какую структуру проекта предлагают Java и maven, я представляю себе это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь и проект серверной части `01-Server`, и проект клиентской части `02-Client` могут ссылаться на общую бизнес-логику `00-CommonBusinessLogic`, которая не зависит ни от каких фреймворков и библиотек, но при этом тестируема (тесты будут в `00-CommonBusinessLogic/Test`). Точка входа в серверное приложение - `01-Server/EntryPoint.java`, точка запуска клиента - `02-Client/EntryPoint.java`.

Теперь пример maven-проекта по умолчанию, который предлагает IntellIJ IDEA:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пока не знаю ВСЕХ ограничений, которые накладывает Java на организацию папок, но хочется вообще убрать `src` со всем содержимым. Так или иначе, вопрос мой такой: насколько возможно приблизить структуру проекта на втором скриншоте к структуре проекта на первом скриншоте? Если понадобятся какие-то специфические настроки maven, то прошу Вас привести фрагмент `pom.xml`.

Comment: В первом скриншоте глупая структура, во втором общепринятая. Ваша проблема решается по-другому. Нужно сделать один проект с модулями. Клиент - Общий API - сервер. Да и общий код клиента и сервера навивает на мысли о возможных проблемах в будущем... Но раз вы пока с ними не столкнулись, то ладно

Comment: @ArchDemon, а почему именно глупая? Такие доводы, как "потому что так никто делает" или "потому что все так делают" или для меня ничего не значат - мне нужны рациональные обоснования. Вы бы не могли конструктивно раскритиковать первую структуру?

Comment: Мне вот непонятно как вы клиент собрались отделять от сервера? Я вам объяснил как решают такую проблему общечеловеки.

Comment: @ArchDemon, тогда позвольте спросить: если, например, есть сущность `User`, которая используется так на клиенте, и на сервере, то она будет лежать в общем API? Или её обычно дублируют в клиентском и серверном модуле?

Comment: Потому что `User` в клиенте и `User` на сервере не одно и тоже. Даже если они совпадают по атрибутам более чем на 90%. Клиенту от сервера Передаётся DTO объект, а на сервере вы оперируете POJO (Entity) объектом. DTO же, в самом общем случае, может содержать не все атрибуты POJO объекта, а может содержать несколько POJO объектов. Поэтому смысл есть выносить именно DTO классы в общий API. Но повторюсь, если вы с проблемами не столкнулись, можете выносить и POJO в общий API

Comment: @ArchDemon, Хорошо, буду тогда разбираться, как разбивать maven на модули. Спасибо Вам за комментарий!

Comment: лучше вообще смотреть в сторону gradle

Comment: @keekkenen, по какой причине?

Comment: @БоковГлеб по причине его гибкости, в управлении проектами/подпроектами в частности

Comment: То что тебе нужно это разбить проект на модули: "Клиент", "Сервер" и "Бизнес логика". В таком случае, ты просто объявишь в модулях клиент и сервер зависимость на модуль бизнес логики и будешь спокойно использовать классы из данного модуля. Как это сделать в Maven можно почитать тут: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#how-do-i-build-more-than-one-project-at-once

Comment: @notaProgrammer, полезная ссылка! Благодарю Вас.